# Find radio and checkbox name using surrounding labeltext with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I'm trying to accomplish the following with Jquery:

When the "No Top" radio-button is "checked" it should disable and "uncheck" any selection done in the Checkbox selection.

If the user select another radio-button option for example "Black Top", the Checkbox selection should be enabled again.

I'm trying to solve this problem  but can't figure out how to find the correct radio-button or checkbox using the labels text (that's all I have to go on). I can't use the ID's because it renders with different names all the time.

Clarification:
The first div class "option-box" contains the radio set which then follows a second div class "option-box" with the checkboxes.
The page have more controls both radio and checkboxes but it is just the checkboxes inside the second "option-class" I'm trying to manipulate.

Any ides?

Here is the code that my controls generate (which I cant modify):

```
<div class="option-box">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input id="ctl00_PageContent_ctl00_KitsList_ctl03_KitComponent_4_0" name="ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl03$KitComponent_4" value="0" checked="checked" type="radio" />
            No Top
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input id="ctl00_PageContent_ctl00_KitsList_ctl03_KitComponent_4_1" name="ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl03$KitComponent_4" value="8" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl03$KitComponent_4$1\',\'\')', 0)" type="radio" />
            Black Top
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input id="ctl00_PageContent_ctl00_KitsList_ctl03_KitComponent_4_2" name="ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl03$KitComponent_4" value="9" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl03$KitComponent_4$2\',\'\')', 0)" type="radio" />
            White Top
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input id="ctl00_PageContent_ctl00_KitsList_ctl03_KitComponent_4_3" name="ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl03$KitComponent_4" value="10" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl03$KitComponent_4$3\',\'\')', 0)" type="radio" />
            Silver Top
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="option-box">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input id="ctl00_PageContent_ctl00_KitsList_ctl04_KitComponent_10_0" name="ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl04$KitComponent_10$0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl04$KitComponent_10$0\',\'\')', 0)" value="11" type="checkbox" />
            Backdoor
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input id="ctl00_PageContent_ctl00_KitsList_ctl04_KitComponent_10_1" name="ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl04$KitComponent_10$1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$KitsList$ctl04$KitComponent_10$1\',\'\')', 0)" value="12" type="checkbox" />
            Topdoor
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all answears, Rory McCrossan solution worked best for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can differentiate the inputs by their `type` attribute, something like this:

```
$('.option-box input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $('.option-box input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
        'disabled': $(this).val() == "0", 
        'checked': false
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hn4z4hbL/)

If there are multiple copies of this `.option-box` structure in the page you can use DOM traversal to find the one related to that which raised the event:

```
$('.option-box input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.option-box').next('.option-box').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
        'disabled': $(this).val() == "0", 
        'checked': false
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hn4z4hbL/1/)

Comment: This will not work, the problem is that the page contains more controls with both radio and checkboxes and I have to select the right one using the label text.
The only thing that is the same every time is "No Top" for the radio label and then the Checkbox area comes right after the radiobutton group (as in the posted code).

Comment: It would have been helpful to know information like that in the original question. I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: Your solution works great with one small problem: It uncheck all checkboxes with every changes to the radio button, not just when selecting "No Top". Very helpful for me if you have the time to fix that, thanks!

Comment: No problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hn4z4hbL/2/. Don't forget to upvote and accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use any id nor the input VALUE, you can try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( '.option-box' ).on( 'click', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
    var labelContent = $( this ).parents(".radio").find( "label" ).html();
    if( labelContent.indexOf( "No Top" ) > -1 ) {
      $( ".checkbox input" ).attr( "disabled", "disabled" ).removeAttr( "checked" );
    } else {
      $( ".checkbox input" ).removeAttr( "disabled" );
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made it generic using `input:`, you can use class to make it specific.

```
$(document).on("click","input:radio",function(){
    if($(this).val() > 0){
        $("input:checkbox").attr("disabled",false);
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox").attr("disabled",true);
        $("input:checkbox").attr("checked",false);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("input:radio").val() > 0){
        $("input:checkbox").attr("disabled",false);
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox").attr("disabled",true);
        $("input:checkbox").attr("checked",false);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gecx62mk/)